# Augmentatives and Diminutives in the Japanese Language?

Tags: words, suffixes, prefixes

**Augmentatives and Diminutives** are modifications (like affixes) that "increase" or "decrease" the "value" of some word's meaning: *Overlord, duckling.*

I found [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/73177/diminutives-in-japanese) question about diminutives on this forum already, is there all that is to it? How about augmentatives?

Therefore my question is:
Could one decrease or increase the meaning of a word like "tree" by modifying the word?
(German example: Baum -> Bäumchen (small) -> Riesenbaum (big)).

***Update:***

[Found some.](https://DOI:10.22059/jflr.2020.305146.733) There are many augmentative morphemes, and they can be read in both ways (japanese and sino-japanese) depending on their host. For example 大 (allomorphs: "dai"/"oo"): 大木 ("daiboku": Big tree), 大雨 ("ooame": Heavy rain).

Others are (with one chosen example.This is no full list.):

- 真 (真白:Pure white),
- 激 (激臭:Sharp smell),
- 過 (過労:Overwork),
- 超 (超電導:Superconductivity),
- 主( 主食:Staple food),
- 正 (正門:Main/"correct" gate).

There are also a bit more complicated 母 (母艦:Main warship/Mothership) and 親 (親柱:Main pillar) which seem to have the meaning of "boss", "main", or "big".

Lastly, augmentation is possible through reduplication, for example 深い/fukai/ -> 深々/fukabuka/(deep -> Very deep).

Comment: What is "megafast"?

Comment: Sorry! Of course this is not a word.

Comment: Some words are designed in such way when drawn, e.g. 木 < 林 < 森

Comment: Good point, however this is not what an augmentative is. But I would be interested in knowing what kind of relation there is between tree and forest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the most straight-up answer is to use 大 and 小.

For example:

- 雪{ゆき}　→ 大雪{おおゆき}
- 川{かわ} → 小川{おがわ}
- 山{やま} → 大山{おおやま}
- 猫{ねこ} → 小猫{こねこ}　(alternatively 子猫{こねこ}・仔猫{こねこ})
- 雨{あめ} → 大雨{たいう}・大雨{おおあめ}
- 木{き} → 大木{たいぼく}
- 樹{き} → 大樹{たいじゅ}
- 牛{うし} → 小牛{こうし} (alternatively 子牛{こうし}・仔牛{こうし}・犢{こうし})
- 鼓{つづみ} → 小鼓{しょうこ}

I think you see the pattern here. While the Kanji is 大 and 小, their reading can vary. On the other hand, with animals, sometimes 子/仔 is used in place of 小 but the reading remains the same. 大 can be おお・だい・たい while 小 can be しょう・こ・お(this one is rare) depending on the combination. You kind of just have to learn them one by one but there is a pattern once you see enough of these.

Comment: [大木]{たいぼく}って、「だいもく」とも読めるのですか？　小鼓は、「こつづみ」だと思っていましたが‥　大雨は「おおあめ」しか知りませんでしたが、調べると、「たいう」とも読めるそうですね（「 **だ**いう」ではなく）

Comment: @Chocolate そっか… 確かに「こつずみ」とか「おおあめ」とかって一番普通な読みですね。でも辞典を調べたら確かに「しょうこ」と「たいう」が見つかりますよ。
なのに「だいもく」と「だいう」の方は確かに間違ってます！ごめんなさい！すぐに編集！

Answer (score 1):

I have never seen 大 and 小 as prefixes. They explicitly tell something is big or small just like 赤 tells something is red.

I can think of only one word that I think more or less fits the definition of a diminutive: 豆. This indicates something is small in size. It only goes with certain words, though.

- 豆電球
- 豆タンク
- 豆柴

As for augmentatives, I think ど might qualify. It indicates the degree of something is greater than normal. It’s informal.

- ど真ん中
- どケチ
- どフリー (completely unmarked in certain sports)